# Not able to test if a checkbox is selected in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to create a test to check if the Select all button in a jqx grid is selected or not. This is the dummy test code I wrote in my jq.spec.js:

```
describe('should check jq widgets', function() {

it('should check if checkbox is checked or not', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get('http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/checkboxselection.htm?arctic');
    browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf($('#contenttablejqxgrid')),50000);
    $("#columntablejqxgrid>div>div>div").click();
        expect($("#columntablejqxgrid>div>div>div").isSelected()).toEqual(true);
    });
});
```

My jq.conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
  framework: 'jasmine',
  specs: ['jq.spec.js'],

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeOutInterval: 3000000
    },
}
```

My test is giving the actual condition as false even when the chechbox is selected.

```
Failures:
1) should check jq widgets should check if checkbox is checked or not
  Message:
    Expected false to equal true.
  Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation
```

I changed my locator multiple times to see if the is with the locator (used different child div, span).

Comment: Can you tell if the checkbox is actually be checked?

Comment: Your selector is finding a 'div', you need to find a checkbox if it is inside this div - expect($("#columntablejqxgrid>div>div>div").isSelected())...

Comment: @jdgower: Yes, I put in some browser.sleep to see that it was getting checked..

Comment: @Grasshopper: I also had a similar thought, what I could not understand though, I checked this on some other similar chechbox and that gives the correct result..Can you plz explain a bit more on how isSelected actually works??

Comment: @Ravi isSelected() works for input html elements with attribute values of  checkbox, radio - http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isSelected. The checkbox in this page gets selected or deselected by using specific classes. You should check the value of the class of the span which changes based on the action. You should look at the answer below for further details.

Comment: Grasshopper: Thanks a lot for your help! This has definitely improved my understanding :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this isn't a standard checkbox, you'll need to handle the state check in *some* way. This example test works for me...

```
describe('should check jq widgets', function() {

    it('should check if checkbox is checked or not', function() {
        var firstCheckbox = $$('.jqx-checkbox-default').first();

        browser.get('http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/checkboxselection.htm?arctic');
        browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf($('#contenttablejqxgrid')),5000, 'grid did not display');
        firstCheckbox.click();

        expect(isChecked(firstCheckbox)).toBe(true);
    });
});

var isChecked = function(element) {
    return element.$('.jqx-checkbox-check-checked').isPresent().then(function(checked) {
         return checked;
    });
};
```

Comment: Hi Brine, I am giving this a go as we speak but am getting `Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.` problems. I have researched these in the past but have not found a concrete ways to avoid these. I have already used conf to set a very high value for jasmine timeout. Any insights here you might have?

Comment: Hey Ravi, I updated my answer with a working test example.

Comment: Thank you! I wrote something on a similar line but am now trying yours. It seems I am having connection issues.